# Creating compile time custom annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

For starters, I used this [sample](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/). I'm running it from eclipse. Simillar to the example given there, I had exported the project containing  annotation processor as a jar file and added it to the list of annotation processors(Project Settings -> Java Compiler ->
Annotation Processing -> Factory path).

But when I compile I don't see any output in console.log as expected.

Do I need to added services in META-INF? (I don't see META-INF folder for eclipse Java projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps outlined in the blog for eclipse didn't work for me. 
But I got it working at command line.

Here is what I tried: [short dive into annotations](http://www.cs-repository.info/2014/08/short-dive-into-annotations.html)